# Migration of Lookup Columns in a Document Library

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, document, library

I have a subsite (and a document library in the subsite) that I need to migrate from development to testing. However, the lookup columns are defined differently in test (as well as in production). When I export from dev and import the site into test, the document library does not display correctly unless I delete all the lookup columns. Is it possible for me to change the definitions of the lookup columns in development to match test (and later change to match production) before migration?

I really wish I do not have to delete the lookup columns because it would require about 70+ document library views to be reconfigured with the appropriate column filters.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you migrating? OOTB I've never seen lookup columns carry over properly. I've always had to recreate them. They sometimes work when we use DocAve to migrate lists, as long as the lists and columns are identical.

Comment: I've tried exporting/importing using just the template (.WSP) as well as using the power shell commands Export-SPWeb and Import-SPWeb with the (.CMP) content migration package files.

The dev environment and it's lookup columns also don't match what our company has in production, so ideally, if I can just change what I currently have to what I need to migrate to, it would be nice. 

I essentially have 70+ views that sort by document type that I need to transfer over correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to take the complete site backup. Then restore it in Production as a different site. Then use Content And Structure to move the libraries to proper place.

Comment: Would it be possible to then copy over the documents in production and keep their column attributes/values?

Comment: Yes. You have lot of flexibility by using Content and Structure options.